# Customize Kendo Line chart?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

]
[image: kendo line chart customization]

Can I achieve the chart like the above with kendo? The idea is the "line" and "Longdash" type in one line.

Any help/suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have separate series for the dashed lines and hide them from legend:

```
series: [{
    name: "India",
    data: [3.907, 7.943, 7.848, 9.284, 9.263, 9.801, 3.890, 8.238, 9.552, null]
},{
    name: "World",
    data: [1.988, 2.733, 3.994, 3.464, 4.001, 3.939, 1.333, -2.245, 4.339, null]
},{
    name: "India-predict",
    data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 9.552, 10.855],
    dashType: "dash",
    visibleInLegend: false,
    color: "red"
},{
    name: "World-predict",
    data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,  4.339, 5.727],
    dashType: "dash",
    visibleInLegend: false,
    color: "red"
}],
```

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/OpaJEf)**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It totally resolves my problem. :)